# Get preferred_username with microsoft graph API

Tags: azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-sdks, microsoft-graph-mail

I'm trying to get the preferred username of a user via the Graph API for Microsoft Office / Azure

If a user logs in via an enterprise application with an `id_token` I get [the `preferred_username` claim](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-optional-claims).

This has the user's actual email address.

If I try to look up the user separately by ID, I can't find any way to get that username.

Seems related to [Sign-in to Azure Active Directory using email as an alternate login ID (preview)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/authentication/howto-authentication-use-email-signin).

The user in question is using a GitHub linked account, it likely has an ugly UPN that I would prefer not to be seen anywhere. Instead I would like to use their `preferred_username`.

Example "ugly" UPN":

```
***_gmail.com#EXT#@***gmail.onmicrosoft.com
```

Comment: One way to do this would be to get the user then use the `displayName` see here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-get?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http. For your use case would you require an email address or would the display name suffice?

Comment: preferred_username which is normally the UPN but not always, e.g. GitHub linked account preferred_username is a sensible username whereas the UPN is something really yuck ***_gmail.com#EXT#@***gmail.onmicrosoft.com

Answer (score 1):

To my knowledge, the `preferred_username` value isn't exposed by Graph in either v1.0 or Beta.

One potential workaround is to use the [`otherMails` property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/user?view=graph-rest-1.0#properties). This is an array, so this may contain multiple entries for a given user. That said, any `otherMails` entry is likely to be less 'ugly'.